# "SQLite Error: No Such Column "even though it's a value

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I am using a room database for my persistance but when I try to retreive "amount" where a I have the column "type" holding a value positive, It gives the following error

```
 [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: negative)
```

Here's my ObjectDAO Query:

```
@Query("SELECT amount FROM `Transaction` WHERE transactionType = `positive`")
int getAmountPositive();
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `'` to enclose string literal instead of "`" (backtick):

```
@Query("SELECT amount FROM `Transaction` WHERE transactionType = 'positive'")
```

Otherwise it is treated as [identifier](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html):

> **'keyword'**      A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
>
> **"keyword"**      A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
>
> **[keyword]**      A keyword enclosed in square brackets is an identifier. This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MS Access
>   and SQL Server and is included in SQLite for compatibility.
>
> ```
> `keyword`
> ```
>
> **A keyword enclosed in grave accents (ASCII code 96) is an identifier.** This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is
>   used by MySQL and is included in SQLite for compatibility.